# Wordpress: Unable to upload file to an existing directory

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

CentOS 6
WP 3.5.1

I have a WP site wich was working Ok and suddenly doesn't allow to upload files:
- Media uploader: Unable to create directory http://subdomain.domain.tld/app/wp-content/uploads/2013/06. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
- Browser uploader: Error saving media attachment.

**The 06 folder already exists and I've been uploading to it without problems.** I've faced this usual problem after installing WP or sometimes when month change but never with an existing folder

I've tried assigning 777 permissions to wp-content, uploads, 2013, 01, 02, ..., 06, setting the owner:group to apache:apache but no way!
I read the reason could be SELinux but
`# getenforce

Disable`

But the most weird thing is now I realized I have the same problem in my localhost!?
OS X 10.6.8
XAMPP 1.7.3

Comment: the owner group should surely be www-data, which is Apache2's process id.

Answer (score 1):

In shell:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/uploads
chmod -R w+g wp-content/uploads
```

Not familiar with CentOS flavour so I may have it all wrong.

**EDIT:**

With a bit of reading around I think I'll take a guess that this is a server issue, in-so-far-as the WordPress framework not getting on with PHP in certain OS environments. It seems some others have had problems creating new 'month' folders in certain server setups. WordPress is supposed to create new folders under the user/group www-data or apache (whichever the correct process alias for Linux), but this can sometimes fail.

Some more suggestions:

1) In WordPress Admin Panel -> Settings -> Media, check that the '*Store uploads in this folder*' textfield is as you would expect it to be. Perhaps even try explicitly giving it the '*app/wp-content/uploads*' pathname.

2) Check some of the old (successfully) uploaded files, and see who owns them. Some people have reported the owner as being '*nobody*', which would obviously be a problem.

3) Slightly more of a hack is unticking the '*Organise my folders into month and year based folders*'. Obviously this will stop WordPress creating new folders based on time...

Also, if you find the solution, remember to switch permissions back to 755. 777 could be a security hazard.

Comment: Thanks, I'd had already done that, in my remote server (apache:apache), local (nobody:nogroup) and 777 permissions in both systems. It seems you have Ubuntu installed

Comment: Try writing to the folder as the apache user while in the system - see if it is a WordPress issue or a Linux issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction, I tested an HTML/PHP application and it can upload the same file to the same folder. So, I'm pretty sure it's a WordPress issue and not a permission problem

Comment: I notice your error (although it is altered by you, presumably) has `/app` before wp-content. I always thought WordPress uploads content straight to `wp-content` in the root directory? Unlikely that this is a problem though. It looks like you may have to go digging into the WP source if you're fearful up upgrading. I recommend running a couple of checks from line `1749` (where it seems your error is being generated) in `wp-includes/functions.php`. Debugging in this way is not ideal, but with the information currently available to me I'm completely stumped as to what this might be.

Comment: You can install WordPress in the root directory or inside a folder. I prefer the second way; for example I have a folder in the root directory where I can make tests without worries about interferences from WordPress rewrite rules, … I'll take a look at functions.php to see what's going on

Comment: Maybe `chmod -R 744 uploads` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Give full permission to wp-content/uploads

chmod -R 777 wp-content/uploads

if you are having cpanel server, do this also

chown -R account_username: wp-content

Comment: Thanks @Leo, changing mode to 777 fixed my problem. I've tried to change mode to 744 like other suggestions, but only 777 fixed my problem.

Comment: yeah. Sometimes full permission needs :)

Comment: This is insecure. Instead do `chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/uploads` and then `chmod -R 744 wp-content/uploads`

Comment: It's been a while I have been into cPanel, however I don't think www-data ownership would work. file/folder clearly required cPanel user_name as user and group. I understand the logic behind the 744 permission but sometimes in cPanel server you should provide full permission, being said I have been into WP and cPanel for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Go the the WordPress -> Settings -> Media and make sure the upload path is the correct path - recommended is the default path.